# Function pointer assignment not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jQuery is :

```
$("#qf").change = calc;
$("#sellers_price").change = calc;

function calc()
{
    var data="";
    $qnty = $("#calQnty");
    $unit = $("#calUnit");
    $price = $("#calPrice");

    var value = this.value;
    if(($("#price_based_on").val()=="Kilos")&&($("#unit").val()=="kg"))
    {
        if(this.value<1)
        {
            $qnty.val((this.value*1000).toFixed(2));
            $unit.val("gm");
            $price.val(($("#sellers_price").val()*value).toFixed(2));
        }
        else if(this.value>=1)
        {
            $qnty.val((this.value*1).toFixed(2));
            $unit.val($("#unit").val());
            $price.val(($("#sellers_price").val()*value).toFixed(2));
        }
    }
    else if(($("#price_based_on").val()=="Kilos")&&($("#unit").val()=="gm"))
    {
        var calQnty = this.value*$(this).parents("tr").find('.qnty').text();
        if(calQnty>=1000)
        {
            $qnty.val((calQnty/1000).toFixed(2));
            $unit.val("kg");
            $price.val(($("#sellers_price").val()*value).toFixed(2));
        }
        else
        {
            $qnty.val(calQnty.toFixed(2));
            $unit.val($("#unit").val());
            $price.val(($("#sellers_price").val()*value).toFixed(2));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $qnty.val((this.value*1).toFixed(2));
        $unit.val($("#price_based_on").val());
        $price.val((json.price*value).toFixed(2));
    }
}
```

Now, due to the lines `$("#qf").change = calc;` and `$("#sellers_price").change = calc;`, whenever the value of either `qf` or `sellers_price` changes, the function `calc()` should be called, right? But when I try it out, it's not working. What am I getting wrong?

I've ensure that the code works when I write it as `$("#qf").change(calc);` but not when it's written the other way as shown in the code. Why does that happen?

Comment: *"should be called, right?*" - of course no. Setting `change` property of jQuery instance has nothing to do with `onchange` event.

Comment: The `.change` property is not a reference to an event handler function like you'd have in the native DOM with `my_elem.onchange = calc`. Instead it's a method to which you pass a function that'll act as the event handler. The corresponding code in the native DOM would be `my_elem.addEventListener("change", calc)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement

```
$("#qf").change = calc;
```

assigns a reference to the `calc()` function to the "change" property of the jQuery object created by `$("#qf")`.  The correct way to set up an event handler is by *calling* `.change()` as you note in your question.

A jQuery object is just an object, and jQuery doesn't set up any fancy getter/setter APIs that *could* work the way your code is written. Your code constitutes a simple JavaScript property assignment that happens not to have any effect as far as event handling goes.

Comment: What does the code `$("#qf").change = calc;` actually do? i.e., What effect does it have?

Comment: @SomenathSinha it's a perfectly OK assignment of the function reference. Like, if you saved `$("#qf")` in a variable, made that assignment, and then called the function, it would call your `calc()` function. Again, a jQuery object is just an object, and property assignment works for those objects just like for any other object.